# Фонетический разбор слов "её" и "еловый"

Tags: фонетический-разбор

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать фонетический разбор слов "её" и "еловый"!

Мы разобрали эти слова так: "йийо" и "йиловый". Но учитель сказала, что правильно — "ийо" и "иловый". Как будет правильно?

Answer (score 3):

Вот этот словарь –

*Каленчук М. Л. **Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка : литературное произношение и ударение начала ХХI века: норма и ее варианты** / М. Л. Каленчук, Л. Л. Касаткин, Р. Ф. Касаткина ; под ред. Л. Л. Касаткина ; Рос. акад. наук, Ин-т рус. яз. им. В. В. Виноградова. – Москва : АСТ-ПРЕСС, 2012. – 1000, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agWcy.jpg) с. – (Фундаментальные словари)* –

– рекомендует произносить ***её*** без йотирования начальной гласной, т. е. примерно так: **[и]ё**, но и вариант с йотированием считает допустимым: **[йи]ё**.

В слове же ***еловый*** йотирование рекомендовано: **[йи]ловый**; в беглой речи возможно произношение и без йотирования: **[и]ловый**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]